# How to differentiate Normal Invoice vs. Recurring Invoice

Tags: acumatica

I need to print some text in report based on only Recurring Invoice in AR Invoice Report. I have tried with below condition

```html
[ARRegister.ScheduleID] <> null And [ARRegister.Scheduled] = 1
```

but seems these is not working. Any suggestion how can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

I was missing another part in the condition. So the correct condition would be as follow

```html
[ARRegister.ScheduleID] <> null And ([ARRegister.Scheduled] = 1 Or [ARRegister.Scheduled] = 0)
```